# can't get contentOffset of tableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I can't get scrolled tableView's position with this code.

```
CGPoint offset =  tableView.contentOffset;
```

I want to scroll tableView on before A ViewController position when I move A ViewController → B ViewController → A ViewController
but it is always "(0,0)"....

**UpDate**------------
I could get contentOffset and implemented it

```
[self.tableView setContentOffset:ScrollOffset animated: YES];
```

But the cell's order has changed.
For example, the cell's order is 1,2,3,4,5,6.
If I select 4th cell,move to next ViewController and come back before ViewController, the cell's order has changed "4,5,6,1,2,3"....
I don't want to change the order.just scroll tableView.

How can I solve it?

Comment: That gets, not sets, the contentOffset.  You can set by assignment `tableView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(...)`, or with `setContentOffset:animated:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can set content offset for UITableView like below, that will scroll your tableview:

```
CGPoint Offset = CGPointMake(0, 60);//pass your values here.
```

setContentOffset like below:

```
[tableView setContentOffset:Offset animated: YES];
```

OR

```
[tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 60) animated: YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

At which point do you try to get the contentOffset?

By using the following delegate function on `UIScrollView` you can get the contentOffset each time the view is scrolled.

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
        NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGPoint(scrollView.contentOffset));

}
```

I hope this helps you find the cause of your problem

Comment: Thanks.I could get contentOffset. But if I select cells, move next ViewController and come back before ViewController, the tableViewCell's order has changed. (cell order:1,2,3,4,5,6→select 4th→come back→cell order:4,5,6,1,2,3)

Comment: The cell order shouldn't be changing, could you add some code that is executed when you select a cell? Maybe that will give more clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Could you describe the question clearly ? We can easily get the contentOffset of tableView in scrollViewDidScroll delegate .